# interchanging limits of a particular double sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose I have a sequence of positive functions $f_n$, and define a double sequence $a_{mn} = \int_{-m}^{m} f_n(x)dx$.

Suppose further that I know for each fixed $m$, I have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{mn} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-m}^{m}f_n(x)dx = 0$ and that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx < K <\infty$ for some constant $K>0$ independent of $n$.

Therefore, for each fixed $n$, the limit $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} a_{mn} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx$ is well defined.

**Question:** Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{mn} = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{mn} = 0$?

My intuition tells me this must be the case, but I haven't been able to construct a reasonable argument using the monotone convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is simply not true. Pick
$$f_n(x)=1_{[n,n+1]}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1,& x\in[n,n+1]\\0,&\mbox{else}.\end{array}\right.$$
Then 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)\, dx = 1,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Now fixate $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and you have $\forall n>m$
$$\int_{-m}^m f_n\, dx=0$$
Hence
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-m}^m f_n\, dx=0.$$

Comment: thankyou, it seems like i am missing a few assumptions / assertions to ensure that this might be possible true